# Email test does not work in Django if django-allauth sends the email

Tags: python, django, email, testing, django-allauth

I use the **Django 5.0.1 with django-allauth**. With real smtp email backend, email confirmation works. Django's email testing features are also working if django-allauth is not involved, like in the [example of the Django testing docs' email service](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/testing/tools/#email-services).

As soon as I want to test the third party django-allauth confirmation email sending function, the *mail.outbox* does not have any item.

My partial test code:

```py
class SignupProcessTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # We setup base form data and we overwrite only test method specific ones
        self.data = {"email": "roland.szucs@booknwalk.com",
                     "password1": "ajtoablak1",
                     "newsletter": 1}
    
    def test_confirmEmailSent(self):
        self.client.post(reverse("account_signup"),
                         self.data,
                         secure=True,
                         follow=True)
        # check email
        self.assertEqual(len(mail.outbox), 1, f"Email was not sent for confirmation:{len(mail.outbox)}")
```

Based on the docs Django just replaces transparently the email backend settings and collects all emails to the *mail.outbox* array. Even Django-allauth should not be aware which email backend serves its email sending request.

When I try this in my local server, after signup I am redirected to another page and I get an email within seconds. Why does not it happen in test environment?

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using APITransactionTestCase instead of TestCase. Maybe it helps...